# Событие мыши перекрывает сигнал нажатия на мышь QT

Tags: c++, qt, события, mouse-event

Есть представление. Требуется при нажатии на кнопку мыши получать событие или сигнал, которые будут содержать индекс элемента на котором была нажата мышь и координаты мыши.

У представления есть сигнал *void pressed(const QModelIndex &index)*, издающийся при нажатии на кнопку мыши, если мышь находится над какой-то записью представления. Если в представлении определить обработчик событий мыши *mousePressEvent* (который содержит координаты нажатия на кнопку), то он забирать себе все нажатия мыши и сигнал *pressed(const QModelIndex &index)* не испускается.

```
class ListView : public QListView
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    ListView() {
        connect(this, SIGNAL(pressed(const QModelIndex &)), this,         
                SLOT(getIndex(const QModelIndex &)));
    }

    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event) {
        qDebug() << event->x() << event->y();
    }

public slots:
    void getIndex(const QModelIndex & index) {
        qDebug() << index.row();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QStringList list;
    list << "a" << "b" << "c";

    QStringListModel model;
    model.setStringList(list);

    ListView view;
    view.setModel(&model);
    view.show();

    return app.exec(); 
}
```

Собственно, как добиться того, что бы при нажатии на кнопку мыши над представлением, ловился сигнал или событие, содержащие и координаты нажатия и индекс элемента?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В классе `QListView` сигнал `pressed` отправляется как раз в обработчике события mousePressEvent, а вы этот обработчик переопределили. Значит, у вас есть 2 пути.

1. Вы должны сами определить по координатам, какой индекс находится под
   мышью в данный момент и отправить сигнал `pressed`. Этот метод
   подходит, если вы реализуете по-настоящему новое представление,
   которого нет в Qt. Например, я делал представление в виде графика, и
   при нажатии мыши я искал, какая линия на графике находится под
   мышью, и вычислял индекс.
2. Вызвать метод `mousePressEvent` класса-родителя. Скорее всего, этот
   метод как раз для вашего случая.

---

```
void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event) {
    qDebug() << event->x() << event->y();
    QListView::mousePressEvent(event);
}
```

Вызывать метод класса-родителя можно в любом месте вашего переопределённого метода, в зависимости от ваших потребностей.

---

UPD. Исходный метод `mousePressEvent` является [protected](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#mousePressEvent). Нужно веское основание, чтобы перенести его в public.